# show the splash screen while the webview loads

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I want to show the splash screen while the webview loads. How ever in this code it waits for the time out time(30 sec) and then shows the webview. I don't know what I am missing ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static Object SPLASH_LOCK = new Object();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

         WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mywebview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
         mywebview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
         mywebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
         mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
         mywebview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
         mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.xxx.com/mobile/index.php?ver=1");

          startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
    }
    public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
        synchronized (SPLASH_LOCK) {
            SPLASH_LOCK.notifyAll();
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }




}
```

And here is the Splash Activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {


    private static String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getName();
    private static long MAX_SPLASH_TIME = 30000;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
          this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar

          setContentView(R.layout.splash);

          new Thread() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  synchronized (MainActivity.SPLASH_LOCK) {
                      // wait for notify or time-out
                      try { MainActivity.SPLASH_LOCK.wait(MAX_SPLASH_TIME); }
                      catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
                  }
                  finish();
              }
          }.start();



       }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `onPageFinished` from `MainActivity` will be never called. Try to extend `WebViewClient` class and override `onPageFinished`. Then create object of this class here

```
mywebview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: I didnt understand , How do I do it ? Can you please help with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can Set background of your main activity instead, it will work the same

Answer (score 0):

What @abc667 means is that you must extend the WebViewClient in this way so it will be called:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
        synchronized (SPLASH_LOCK) {
            SPLASH_LOCK.notifyAll();
        }
    }   
}
```